# open a File Download dialog in SharePoint webpart

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I have created a webpart for SharePoint 2007, which has a button and a link( `http://ABC:19896/TestDocs/User1.zip`).
In click-event of the button, how can I open a File Download dialog and download this user.zip?

```
Button btn = new Button();
string str = "http://ABC:19896/TestDocs/User1.zip";
in createchildcontrols(){
//some code
btn.Text = "Download";
btn.click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
//remaining code 
}

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //open the file download dialog and download the file by using str     
}
```

Thanks and Regards,

Andres.

Answer (score 1):

This could be one of the simplest solution. Clicking on this will work.

```
<a href="http://ABC:19896/TestDocs/User1.zip" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Comment: In webpart I have added Button btn = new Button(); and handled its click event. How can I add the above in the webpart?

Comment: u can use Hyperlink instead of button.

Comment: no, HyperLink will not serve the requirement.

Comment: could u pls briefly explain ur requirement.

Comment: I have edit the post. @Pushendra : In Btn_click event is it possible to download an item by your logic or using something like 'windows.location = 'link'"?

Comment: pls have a look at this post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance. I looked for some .NET stuff, not scripts. I solved it by "Response.AddHeaders(..,..)".